# Is this a good implementation of a simple "Size" value type

Tags: c#, .net, reinventing-the-wheel

I have created the value type below to represent the desired size for an image. The `Size.Default` is used in situations where the image is required in the size it was supplied in, i.e. the image shouldn't be resized.

Is this a good implementation of a value type, especially regarding the `IEquatable<T>` implementation?

What are your thoughts on the use of the private constructor to create the `Default` instance?

```
using System;

public struct Size : IEquatable<Size>
{
    private readonly int _height;
    private readonly int _width;
    private readonly bool _default;

    public static readonly Size Default = new Size(true);

    public int Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
    }

    public bool IsDefault
    {
        get { return _default; }
    }

    private Size(bool isDefault)
    {
        _height = 0;
        _width = 0;
        _default = isDefault;
    }

    public Size(int width, int height)
    {
        _height = height;
        _width = width;
        _default = false;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals((Size)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(Size other)
    {
        if (this._default && other._default)
            return true;

        if (this._default && !other._default)
            return false;

        if (!this._default && other._default)
            return false;

        return this.Width == other.Width && this.Height == other.Height;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Size left, Size right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Size left, Size right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static Size Parse(string input)
    {
        var parts = input.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length != 2)
            throw new FormatException("Input string was not in a correct format.");

        var x = int.Parse(parts[0]);
        var y = int.Parse(parts[1]);

        return new Size(y, x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Size.aspx)?

Comment: @JeffMercado Nothing, but I'm trying to learn something and get some feedback on the code I've written. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the point is for making a distinction between a size and the default size.  But you shouldn't expose the default value as a field, use a property.  That will give you much more flexibility should you decide to do other things when getting the value.  No need for a backing field, it's a value type and it isn't all that complex.

```
public static Size Default
{
    get { return new Size(true); }
}
```

Consider renaming `_default` to something that would indicate it is a `bool`.  I'd usually go with something like `_isDefault`.  You already did that for the constructor parameter and property, I don't know why you didn't do the same for the field.

Your `Equals()` method should not ever throw exceptions.  What would happen if you passed in something that was not a `Size`?

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (other is Size)
        return Equals((Size)other);
    return false;
}
```

Your `Equals(Size)` method is a little unusual.  You can merge the second and third conditions into a single `this._isDefault != other._isDefault`.  It might make more sense to combine that test with the tests for width and heights.  And personally, I wouldn't mix accessing fields and properties within a single method, I'd choose one or the other unless the properties had other logic that I needed to be fired.

```
public bool Equals(Size other)
{
    if (this._isDefault && other._isDefault)
        return true;

    return this._isDefault == other._isDefault &&
           this._width == other._width &&
           this._height == other._height;
}
```

Any time you override the equals method, you *must* override the `GetHashCode()` method too.  Use an implementation something like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hashCode = 79;
        hashCode = hashCode * 97 + _isDefault.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * 97 + _width.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * 97 + _height.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

While we're on the subject of overriding methods, you should consider overriding the `ToString()` method as well to return something reasonable.

Your `Parse()` method should do more validation than that IMHO.  You make the assumption that the input will be a comma separated pair of values.  You check if you have a pair which is good, but you should explicit perform checks to make sure the values are integer numbers (i.e., digits).  It's not as useful receiving a generic format exception coming from the `int.Parse()` method than if it came from *your* `Parse()` method.  On a minor note, use `width` and `height` for the local variables and not `x` and `y`... that's not what they're representing.

Comment: Since you mention shortening Boolean tests in `Equals(Size)`, you can also shorten the test in `Equals(object)` with `return (other is Size) && this.Equals((Size)other);`

Comment: True, though for that particular case, I would leave it as-is. I'd rather leave type-checking as separate steps.

Comment: I agree with Jeff, their is better readability with two separate statements.

Comment: Thanks Jeff with regard the formula of `GetHashCode`, are the 79 and 97s purely arbitrary values or is there some thought behind those choices?

Comment: I like your point about using fields or properties only, and the `is Size` for `Equals(object)` is a good, if not obvious catch. Thanks again

Comment: The numbers chosen in the `GetHashCode()` method should be prime numbers.  I generally use those two because they mirror each other.

Comment: The code for `GetHashCode` is very verbose. Doesn't C# offer something like Java's `Objects.hash(...)`, which you can then call as `Objects.hash(_isDefault, _width, _height)`? This would avoid the question about where the numbers 79 and 97 come from.

Answer (score 3):

Other than needing to override `GetHashCode()`, it looks pretty darn tip-top (adapted from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/3312)):

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // Overflow is fine, just wrap.
    unchecked
    {
        var hash = 17;

        // Suitable nullity checks etc., of course :)
        hash = (hash * 23) + this._height.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 31) + this._width.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 41) + this._default.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

As a matter of style, I'm not a fan of making fields `public`, no matter how `static` or `readonly` they are, so I'd prefer to do this:

```
private static readonly Size _defaultSize = new Size(true);

public static Size Default
{
    get { return _defaultSize; }
}
```

Lastly, you might want to override `ToString()` to provide the "reverse" of what `Parse()` does; that is, a string of height and width separated by a comma.

**ETA: Welcome to 2021 where `DefaultSize` listed above may now be simplified to**

```
public static Size Default { get; } = new Size(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, with regard the formula of `GetHashCode`, where do the 17,23,31 and 41 come from? Are they purely arbitrary values or is there some thought behind those choices?

Comment: They come from a book called "Effective Java". They're prime numbers, which makes their inclusion in multiplication operations yield a better distribution of hash values within a given set (in this case, the set represented by the range of the `int` type).

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a `Parse` method you [should supply a corresponding `TryParse` method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/vexing-exceptions) as well (and it makes sense to implement the former in terms of the latter).

Other than that, and the comments already mentioned, this is a very clean implementation.

One potential gripe that I have is that `Default` and width/height are mutually exclusive so it might not make sense to provide them in the same interface. Other languages (Haskell …) would implement this cleanly as a [discriminate union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (that is, a type that is *either* a default size *or* provides a custom width and height).

In .NET you could use subclassing (with `DefaultSize` and `CustomSize` having a common base class `AbstractSize`) but I guess at that point we have rightly concluded that this is over-engineering and your solution is both simpler and more efficient.

Comment: +1 for tagged union. Languages like Nemerle make this kind of data structure a dream `variant Size { | Default | Other { width : int, height : int } }`

Answer (score 2):

Overall, the code is good on a technical level. This answer addresses the design philosophy behind it, because I think you've overthought the default size approach to the point of generating more work and complexity without actually adding value. We've all been there :-)

> The Size.Default is used in situations where the image is required in the size it was supplied in, i.e. the image shouldn't be resized.

I think you've inverted the logic here. The `Size` struct is immutable. It can never change its values (i.e. "resize") regardless of which initial size you picked.

You cannot force your consumer to choose a default size. The consumer picks what they want, i.e. whether they fall back on a default or not. Whether that choice is correct is not the responsibility of the `Size` class, similar to how a hammer is not responsible for you using it to kill someone with it.

The `Size` class cannot be held responsible for allowing resizing or not. At best, your `Size` object can prevent *itself* to be modified post-construction, but a consumer can always discard a `Size` object and create a new one, or resize images without even using your `Size` object to begin with.

What I want to get at here is that there's nothing wrong with defining a default size to make your consumer's life easier, but you shouldn't expect this to be able to control your consumer's behavior.

Defining a default size is fine:

```
public static readonly Size Default = new Size(true);
```

Though a slight improvement would be to generate a new `Size` object every time it is accessed, to avoid nasty interactions (unless you blindly trust your ability to keep this struct immutable):

```
public static Size Default => new Size(true);
```

*Ignore the constructor arguments for now, I'll address this later on.*

However, the part where you pass the "default" boolean into the constructor, and what you do with `_default` afterwards, is unnecessary and leads to some complex and clumsy juggling. I think the intention was good but you stuck with the design when it got hairy, instead of redesigning it.

One of the reasons that leads me to this suggestion is the realization that your current setup distinguishes between two size objects with the same width and height, based on whether they were explicitly set or fell back on using the default values. That makes no sense. A size of 3x3 is the same as a size of 3x3, regardless of how you decided to use those dimensions. A $100 bill is worth the same regardless of how you came to acquire it.

It would be better to not track `_default` in any way, since you're better off not using it anyway. As I see it, you are using it for two things:

- `_default` is used to check for equality

But as I established above, that's actually counterproductive. Two sizes with the same dimensions are equal, regardless of how those dimensions were decided. This drastically simplifies the equality logic:

```
public bool Equals(object other)
{
    return other is Size otherSize               // Are we comparing Size objects?
           && this.Width == otherSize.Width      // Same width?
           && this.Height == otherSize.Height;   // Same height?
}
```

- `_default` provides the value for the `IsDefault` property

But you can do it without needing `_default`, if you check it on the fly. Remember that you can access your static `Default` for this. Also remember how we just refactored your `Equals` logic. That leads us to the neat implementation of:

```
public bool IsDefault => this.Equals(Default);
```

Now you get an accurate reading on whether a size matches the default size or not.

> What are your thoughts on the use of the private constructor to create the Default instance?

Forgetting context for a while, you've used a private constructor correctly on a technical level. This is the general kind of use case that a private constructor is designed for.

Based on my previous suggestion, I wouldn't use the private constructor here though, because when you do not track `_default`, your object ceases to need this distinction between constructors.

Instead, you can just use the public one, and input whatever values you with to have as default values:

```
public static Size Default => new Size(0, 0);
```

Intuitively, it makes more sense that the `Default` is now grouped together with the actual *default* values themselves. In your code, the default values were off on their own in a constructor.

Note that if you so choose, you can use constant values here. I don't consider it necessary in this case, but others prefer this as a default style:

```
public const int DefaultWidth = 0;
public const int DefaultHeight = 0;
public static Size Default => new Size(DefaultWidth , DefaultHeight );
```

---

One more mention, always think about your consumer. I noticed that in your `Parse` method, you invert the order of the arguments:

```
var x = int.Parse(parts[0]);
var y = int.Parse(parts[1]);

return new Size(y, x);
```

This means that for your consumer, there are two different orders. This object:

```
new Size(123, 456);
```

is not the same as this object:

```
Size.Parse("123,456");
```

but it is the same as this object:

```
Size.Parse("456,123");
```

That's really counterintuitive and is going to lead to your consumer making mistakes. I suggest sticking to one specific order for the parameters so that your consumer doesn't need to keep guessing which order it is.

By far the most common is `width,height` due to the established x/y axes convention in mathematics.